# AWS EC2 Wordpress Gutena Form - Sorry! your form was not submitted properly, Please try again later

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, forms, amazon-ec2, mailing

I created an EC2 in AWS and installed a wordpress on it. Security group inbound ports are 22, 80 and 443 from my IP, outbound - everything. I'm trying to create a petition raising tool and I thought that I will collect people's support with Gutena Form. Later on I would like the form to send a message to Amazon SES -> Lambda -> DynamoDB. But my test form is not working. When try to submit the vote I can see error message: Sorry! your form was not submitted properly, Please try again later. I used basic settings and didn't turn recaptcha on.

What should I do to make it work? Is is something about AWS security group? Or should I enable external mailing service?

Thanks in advance.

I tried enabling recaptcha and using another form plugins (ninja form and formidable forms) but it didn't help.

Comment: You might get a better response at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/